# Asp.Net - (Sql) The connection was not closed

Tags: sql, asp.net, connection

I have a problem which is always happen to my website. Whatever I tried I couldn't get rid of this.

In my asp.net project, Im using microfost azure server and database. I checked all of my queries again and again. Whereever I open the connection after that I close it for sure.

Also before I open my sql connection almost every functions I check connection state like :

```
if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Close(); }
```

If I refresh my main page several times I got the error, most of the time without any multiple refresh I got the same.

```
**The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
```

Can anyone help me about what can I do in this situation ?

Comment: Do you have any other connections? Are you opening the connection anywhere else?

Comment: Did you try wrapping in a try-catch and debugging to see for sure where the exception is raised?

Comment: @pookie I open my sql connection at before every sending command and close it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception likely indicates that the connection is already open when you're trying to open it. Are you sharing a global connection that's used by multiple processes on different threads? That would cause it and might also explain why the problem is intermittent.

The `InvalidOperationException` is mentioned in the documentation for [`SqlConnection.Open()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx).

It's best to explicitly create a new connection each time you need one and then call `Dispose()` when you're done. You can call `Close()`, but an easier pattern is `using`, like

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    connection.Open() // open it right before you execute something
}
```

The `using` statement ensures that `Dispose()` is always called. `Dispose()` calls `Close()`. So if you create connections as above, your connection will always get closed.

Behind the scenes when you `Close()` or `Dispose()`, the framework isn't *really* closing the connection. At least not right away. It keeps a pool of opened connections and re-uses them because it's more efficient than opening and closing connections. So if you open a connection, close it, open another with the same connection string, close it, and so on, chances are that behind the scenes it's actually the exact same connection. But the framework is handling that for you behind the scenes. If a connection isn't used then the connection *really* gets closed. See [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

So while it might seem efficient to try to re-use the same `SqlConnection`, it's really okay to just create and `Dispose()` as needed, and let the connection pooling manage the lifetime of the connection behind the scenes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.In that case I have one more question before I try it. What about if I use webconfig connectionString each time I need it and after using dispose it ?

Comment: Web.config connectionStrings is just a place to store connection strings, so it doesn't affect how connections are opened or closed.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check the exception while closing connection.

```
try{
    stmt.close();
    connection.close();
    connection = null;
}catch(Exception e){
    try{
        connection.close();
        connection = null;
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```